# Storing simulation results as data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table, plyr

I've to do plenty of simulation and it takes lot of time. I think processing time can be reduced through `data.table`. How can I store the results of `mdply(data.frame(prob=seq(from = 0.1, to = 0.9, by = 0.1)), rbinom, n = 5, size = 2)` into `data.table` without saving its output first to `data.frame`.

```
library(plyr)
df1 <- mdply(data.frame(prob=seq(from = 0.1, to = 0.9, by = 0.1)), rbinom, n = 5, size = 2)
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(df1)
```

**Edited**

I know that I can use `setDT(df1)` to avoid the creating to `dt1`. However, the main problem is about `mdply` which creates a `data.frame` which consumes a lot of time.

Comment: If you use `setDT(df1)` it turns `df1` into a data.table "by reference" and you don't need to assign the result/create another object (you can look at the docs about it). I don't read plyrish so I can't comment on changing that.

Comment: Yes, I know that I can use `setDT(df1)` to avoid the creating to `dt1`. However, the main problem is about `mdply` which creates a `data.frame`.

Comment: Why don't yout turn it into a `data.table` before you run `rbinom`?

Comment: Ok, now I see. One general point: simulations are much faster with matrices. So if processing time is your concern, learn to use matrices instead of packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plyr` and `data.table` are for very similar purposes, so you usually don't need to switch back and forth between the two at all. You can do everything with `data.table` in this case:

```
dt = data.table(prob = seq(0.1, 0.9, by = 0.1))
dt = dt[, as.list(rbinom(prob, n = 5, size = 2)), by = prob]
dt
   prob V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1:  0.1  0  0  0  0  0
2:  0.2  0  0  0  0  1
3:  0.3  1  2  1  0  1
4:  0.4  1  1  2  1  0
5:  0.5  2  2  1  1  1
6:  0.6  1  1  0  0  1
7:  0.7  2  1  2  1  0
8:  0.8  2  1  2  0  1
9:  0.9  2  2  2  2  2
```

I would add that my hunch is that the fastest way to do this would be to make the matrix first and then assign columns.

```
> mat = mapply(rbinom, prob = dt$prob, n = 5, size = 2)
> cbind(dt, t(mat))
   prob V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1:  0.1  0  0  0  0  0
2:  0.2  1  0  0  1  1
3:  0.3  1  1  1  0  0
4:  0.4  1  0  2  1  1
5:  0.5  1  1  1  0  2
6:  0.6  2  0  2  1  1
7:  0.7  1  1  1  2  1
8:  0.8  1  2  1  0  2
9:  0.9  1  1  2  1  1
```

A very quick test on an 8000 row table shows this is faster:

```
> dt = data.table(prob = (seq(0.1, 0.9, by = 0.00001)))
> system.time(for(i in 1:10) dt[, as.list(rbinom(prob, n = 5, size = 2)), by = prob])
   user  system elapsed 
   6.14    0.00    6.16 
> system.time(for(i in 1:10) {mat = mapply(rbinom, prob = dt$prob, n = 5, size = 2) ; cbind(dt, t(mat))})
   user  system elapsed 
   2.61    0.00    2.62
```

And both are a substantial improvement on the original:

```
> system.time(for(i in 1:10) {df1 = mdply(df, rbinom, n = 5, size = 2) ; dt1 = data.table(df1)})
   user  system elapsed 
 152.23   46.60  200.07
```

Comment: Also fast is storing in long format `system.time(for(i in 1:10){dt2 <- dt[,rbinom(prob, n = 5, size = 2), by = prob][,ind:=paste0("V",1:5)]})` if one really wants it in wide format, there's still the fairly fast `dcast(dt2,prob~ind,value.var="V1")` I see the combo as about 2x as fast as the `as.list` approach.